# Python Comprehension - Replace Nested Loop

Tags: python, data-structures

Working on the 'two-sum' problem..

Input: An unsorted array A (of integers), and a target sum t

The goal: to return a list of tuple pairs (x,y) where x + y = t

I've implemented a hash-table H to store the contents of A. Through use of a nested loop to iterate through H, I'm achieving the desired output. However, in the spirit of learning the art of Python, I'd like to replace the nested loop with a nice 1-liner using comprehension & a maybe lambda function? Suggestions?

Source Code:

```
import csv
with open('/Users/xxx/Developer/Algorithms/Data Structures/_a.txt') as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter ='\n')
    hash_table = {int(num[0]):int(num[0]) for(num) in csv_reader}    #{str:int}


def two_sum(hash_table, target):
    pairs = list()
    for x in hash_table.keys():
        for y in hash_table.keys():
            if x == y:
                continue
            if x + y == target:
                pairs.append((x,y))
    return pairs
```

Comment: Can you add a sample input list? Without that file we can't test run your code and suggest alternatives.

Comment: hint: to generate all the pairs you could write `[(a1, a2) for a1 in A for a2 in A] `

Comment: I suggest you try to do it yourself and if it does not work, try to research why, and if you still cannot understand why, try to ask a more specific question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have two ranges and you want to loop both of them separately to get all the combinations as in your case, you can combine the loops into one using `itertools.product`. You can replace the code below

```py
range1 = [1,2,3,4]
range2 = [3, 4, 5]
for x in range1:
    for y in range2:
        print(x, y)
```

with

```py
from itertools import product

for x, y in product(range1, range2):
    print(x, y)
```

Both code blocks produce

```
1 3
1 4
1 5
2 3
2 4
2 5
3 3
3 4
3 5
4 3
4 4
4 5
```

But you would still need the `if` check with this construct. However, what `product` returns is a generator and you can pass that as the iterable to `map` or `filter` along with a lambda function.

In your case you only want to include pairs that meet the criteria. Thus, `filter` is what you want. In my simple example, if we only want combinations whose sum is even, then we could do something like

```
gen = product(range1, range2)
f = lambda i: (i[0] + i[1]) % 2 == 0
desired_pairs = filter(f, gen)
```

This can be written as a one-liner like

```
desired_pairs = filter(lambda i: (i[0] + i[1]) % 2 == 0, product(range1, range2))
```

without being too complicated for being understood.

Note that like `product` and `map`, what filter returns is a generator, which is good if you are just going to loop over it later to do some other work. If you really need a list just do convert it to a list as

```py
desired_pairs = list(filter(lambda i: (i[0] + i[1]) % 2 == 0, product(range1, range2)))
```

If we print this we get

```
[(1, 3), (1, 5), (2, 4), (3, 3), (3, 5), (4, 4)]
```